# Sending an email with powershell but some recipients don´t receive the mail

Tags: powershell

I have trouble sending a PowerShell email to various recipients. Some of them get the email but some do not. I do not know why, but if I send an email manually they do get it, but if I do it with the following script, they don't.

```bsh
$Email       = "example1@ex.com.ar", "example2@ex.com.ar", "example3@ex.com.ar", "example4@ex.com.ar"
$Internal    = "example5@ex.com.ar", "example6@ex.com.ar",
$Subject     = "Test - $(Get-Date -format dd/MM/yy)"

[array]$attachments = Get-ChildItem "\\server\folder\destination" *.pdf

if ([array]$attachments -eq $null) {
}

else {

    $Msg = @{
        to          = $Email
        cc          = $Internal
        from        = "anemail.mail@mailmail.com.ar"
        Body        = 'x,','x.','x,','x'-join '<br />'
        subject     = "$Subject"
        smtpserver  = "example@example.com.ar"
        BodyAsHtml  = $True
        Attachments = $attachments.fullname
    }

    Send-MailMessage @Msg
}
```

I thought of an email array to solve this, but even if i test with only the email that do not receive the emails, but it does not work either.

Comment: Can you safely rule out that your sending mail service isn't blocking your batch sending as possible spam to prevent getting blackisted?

Comment: I don't believe the at sign `@` is valid for the SmtpServer name

Comment: @Filburt all email recipients are in the same service "@example.com.ar". I would have to ask if something is preventing on sending to them, cuz i don´t have more access than this.

Comment: @Theo how is that?

Comment: @Santiago Is your `from` actually also `@example.com.ar`? This is mostly a matter of finding out the difference between your sending manually and sending by script.

Comment: See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and)